# SQL Recursive get next algorithm not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Trying to make a get next recursive algorithm in stored procedure. I am having a bit of difficulty however. The condition part sometime may select multiple result - if that is the case I want it to continue looking for case without any result in order to select my available next number. I tried using top 1, exists sub query etc - most of those cannot be used inside of the recursion.

Here is a sample code for illustration purposes:

```
declare @inputAccID int,
        @accDtlID  int

WITH cte_table AS (
    SELECT       
       number   ,
     accc_id as id
    FROM       
        Account
    WHERE acc_id = @inputAccID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        cte.number +1
    FROM cte_table cte
     join
        AccountDetails ad on cte.id = a.acc_id
        join Account a on a.acc_id = ad.acc_id
        Where ad.accDtl_id != @accDtlID 
          and ad.number = ad.number
)
SELECT * FROM cte_table;
Options(maxrecursion 0)
```

basically I want to get next number when there is no other record in the database with the same number so it will be unique in the database. However in the database currently there are cases when the condition returns multiple records - seems like bad data. That breaks the recursion

Any technique that can check only if it records exists or not?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: This sounds like bad idea. If you would like to get unique data, you should use constraint (autoincrement).

Comment: @jarih MS SQL Server

Comment: @Maciej Los  currently the store procedure is using recursion anyway by calling verify and get next 2 more procedures anyway. The idea is to improve performance in this case since we are seeing some serious performance issues. Auto-increment not an option in this case

Comment: If you're looking for the next number so you can insert a new record with that number you're basically creating a race condition where two or more users could try to create a record with the same number. [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) and [Sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) exist to avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: You need to add sample data and expected results to clarify your question. But in general if you want to get your own "max" value you need to lock the table while you do it to prevent other users modifying it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning there is no such risk. The process that is using the algorithm is processor initiated and is scheduled. It is also in transaction so the data would be safe. The previous recursive system has been working generally well up until recently. That up there is a possible way to improve upon its performance. The business need does not need revision at this point